# xaml Grid Layout Not extending across whole screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

I have the following grid layout inside a `stacklayout` in my xamarin.forms app.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              // 5 more auto height rows
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <RowDefinition Height="*" />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image  Source="Logo.png"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

        //some more labels etc.

        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="ScanActivity" 
                           Color="Black"
                           HorizontalOptions="End"
                           VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                           Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="1" />

  </Grid>
```

I would like the activity indicator to be in the bottom right hand corner of my app screen. However, it currently comes at the bottom right hand corner of my content, which is about 1" above where I would like it. How to I drive the bottom row to fill all the screen and then put that item at the bottom of it? I thought that was what the `"*"` height did?

Comment: Your page contains only this grid?

Comment: As far as I know, auto adjusts a cell to the dimensions of the item placed inside, and * Takes up the remaining white space. Try, placing your grid into a parent grid with no definitions, and force the activity indicator h and v placed to bottom right.

Comment: @E-Bat Yes, only contains this grid in a stacklayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the `StackLayout`, once removed, these functions worked properly!